# Passing an array through a member function and setting a new array with its value in F#

Tags: arrays, class, f#, copy, member

Code:

```
 open System
 open System.Net
 open System.IO

 type Student(x:string, y:int[]) = class

    let mutable id = x
    let mutable scores = y
    new() = Student("", [|-1;-1;-1;-1;-1|])
    member this.setScores(a:int[])
        scores = Array.copy a   
    member this.setId(s:string)=
        id <- s
    member this.getId() =
        id
    member this.getScores() = 
        scores

end

let students = [|for i in 1 .. 30 -> new Student() |]

students.[0].setId("c1234501")
students.[0].setScores([|10; 20; 10; 30; 30|])
```

---

So I have this class and I need to be able upon request set the array scores to an array I 
pass in to the member function. I have tried things like scores <- a but it says there's an error and it expects another token that's not the <- such as =. When I use the = though, it doesn't transfer the value of the passed in array so when I print it out I just get the default array values. I am new to F# and seem to be terrible with the syntax. My goal I will state again just to clarify : I want to pass in an array through a member function and then set that passed in value to the value of the array scores in my Student class objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `setScores` member should be:

```
member this.setScores(a:int[]) =
    scores <- Array.copy a
```